# How to queue up simultaneous signed transactions

Tags: web3js, parity, raw-transaction, nonce

I have written a simple API server in `NodeJS` that uses `web3` (version 1 beta 27) to interact with a remote Parity node.

The guts of the call is as follows

```
const invoke = async (req, res) => {
  const { params: { address } } = req
  try {
    const theContract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, contractAddress, { from: SENDER_ADDRESS })
    const fn = theContract.methods.doTheThing(address)
    const account = web3.eth.accounts.privateKeyToAccount(PRIVATE_KEY)
    const data = fn.encodeABI()
    const nonce = await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(SENDER_ADDRESS, 'pending')
    const payload = {
      nonce,
      data,
      gas,
      from: SENDER_ADDRESS,
      to: contractAddress
    }
    const signedTx = await account.signTransaction(payload, account.privateKey)
    const { rawTransaction } = signedTx
    const response = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(rawTransaction)
    const { transactionHash: tx } = response
    res.json({ tx })
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({ error: err.message })
  }
}
```

This works perfectly if I only make one call to the API at a time, and it even works fine if I make a few calls that roughly overlap. (tested it with curl using a number of terminal windows)

But if I use a script to call the API many times simultaniously (which is a reasonable simulation of a real-world condition) most of the calls fail, saying `There is another transaction with same nonce in the queue.`

One solution that's been recommended to me is to create a `personal` address within Parity itself rather than creating an address in the form of a public/private key pair on my machine, but that does not seem like a best-practice solution.

The issue is that `web3.eth.getTransactionCount(SENDER_ADDRESS, 'pending')` is returning the same `nonce` if the API is invoked too quickly. One thought is that I could simply retry if the caught error includes the `There is another transaction with same nonce in the queue.` message but that seems fragile to say the least.

What is the correct way to queue up simultaneous requests like this?

Comment: you will have to implemented your own logic to handle the nonce. This is a very common issue. The simplest you can do is get the nonce once from the node and the increment it in memory every time you want to sign and send a new transaction. This is a very naive approach, of course as. You will have to take care of failed transaction e.g. due to network error and make sure you do no create a nonce gap i.e. send transaction with bigger nonce than the current one

Comment: Did you find a good solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use batch request, it allows you to send in a specific order transactions:

http://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth.html?highlight=batch#batchrequest

Comment: batch request does not help as each API call is entirely independent from each other.

Comment: I don't understand. What is the problem? batch lets you queue up whetever call/transaction you want to make. It does not care about what's inside.

Comment: The API only calls the function with one address.  Thousands of independent external entities can invoke the API.  Each call to the API is exclusive of each other so there is nothing to batch.

Comment: Oh, ok, misunderstanding. In my knowledge, there is no way to do that. Blockchain is not something meant to be fast (at least for now)